# action: push: unauthorized to harbor registry with OIDC

Tags: docker, harbor

I have a new instance of Harbor with OIDC enabled. I can log into the web portal just fine. However when I am trying to do a docker login it fails as follows

Error response from daemon: Get "https://myharborurl": **unauthorized: authentication required**

The core.log shows

Jul 19 16:42:41 xxxxxxxx core[2104879]: 2023-07-19T16:42:41Z [ERROR] [/server/middleware/security/oidc_cli.go:62][requestID="1fc3f9c5-b2e3-4e0c-9c31-a6bee346b741"]: failed to verify secret, username: 'myname@mycompany.com', **error: failed to get oidc user info, error: no row found**

Jul 19 16:42:41 xxxxxxxx core[2104879]: 2023-07-19T16:42:41Z [ERROR] [/server/middleware/security/basic_auth.go:72][client IP="10.91.17.18" requestID="1fc3f9c5-b2e3-4e0c-9c31-a6bee346b741" user agent="docker/24.0.2 go/go1.20.4 git-commit/659604f kernel/5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.2 (windows))"]: **failed to authenticate user:'myname@mycompany.com', error:not supported**

Any idea?

Comment: so robot account works. But OIDC does not. Is docker with OIDC not supported?